# Get string inside square brackets with javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this script to handle a form and preview a background change:

```
if(!options) {
        var optionsTemp = $manageBackgroundForm.serializeArray();

        var regex =/\bg[[a-z]+\]/;
        $.each(optionsTemp, function(index, options) {
            var test = options.name.match(regex);
            debug(test[0]); // DONT WORK 

        });

        var options = new Object();
        options.color = 'red';
        options.image = 'test.png';
        options.position = '20px 20x';
        options.attachment = 'fixed';
        options.repeat = 'repeat-x';
        options.size = 'cover';
    }

    $('body').css({
        'background-color': options.color,
        'background-image': 'url('+options.image+')',
        'background-position': options.position,
        'background-attachment': options.attachment,
        'background-repeat': options.repeat,
        'background-size': options.size  //contain
     });
```

My inputs are like input name="bg[color]" . I use it like this to easy handle the form in PHP. But I am having problems handling it in javascript. I want to get all the BG options  (and only the bg options) from my form - I have other inputs like val[example].

I want to map the inputs with the options. Any idea?

Comment: You're not escaping regex properly try with this: `/\bg\[\w+\]/`

Comment: If you know for a fact that there's always square brackets in the name then this will get the string inside them...  `var test = options.name.split("[")[1].split("]")[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an explanation of your regex:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  g                        'g'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [[a-z]+                  any character of: '[', 'a' to 'z' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
```

I'm sure that isn't what you want.

Try this one instead:

```
/\bbg\[[a-z]+\]/
```

Note the `b` after the word boundary.

Comment: Did you use any special software to generate this explanation text ? I really could use it to be less annoyed by my very-bad-at-regex collegues :)

Comment: @OcuS: It's a perl module availlable at http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm